# Make select list editable on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My page loads with a populated select box inside of `<td>` tag. I need to be able to click on the select list and it become editable and populated with other values from database.

I've tried adding a function inside of the click event that populates the list when new data is being inserted. But the logic is slightly different from that and I'm sure how to apply to the click event.

HTML:

```
<td> <div class='edit'><select contenteditable='true' class='positionList_<?php echo $id; ?>'><option value='<?php echo $pID; ?>'><?php echo $name; ?></option></select> </div> </td>
```

Beginning of function.

```
    var checkedStatus = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(e) {
       //e.preventDefault();
       $(this).addClass('editMode');
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           checkedStatus = 1;
       } else {
           checkedStatus = 0;
       }
```

This is code that populates the select list on an insert of new data. But this needs to populate the list on and edit.

```
       var data
       $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'get-position.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          var html_to_append = '';
          $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            html_to_append += '<option value="' + item.positionID + '">' + item.name + '</option>';
          });
          $(".positionList").html(html_to_append);
        },
      }) 

    });
```

This is the code that updates the database.

```
    // Save data
    $(".edit").focusout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("editMode");

        var id = this.id;
        var split_id = id.split("_");
        var field_name = split_id[0];
        var edit_id = split_id[1];

        var value = $(this).text();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'update.php',
            type: 'post',
            //data: { field:field_name, value:value, id:edit_id },
            data: { field:field_name, value:value, id:edit_id, checked:checkedStatus },
            success:function(response){            
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply populate it on page load?

Comment: @scatter On page load it is populated with a value from the database, not the full list. My idea was to be able to click on the list and then it populate with the rest of the values, then when the user clicks off of the list the data would be updated in the database.

Comment: you could do the same you did on first load once you click the <td>.